# Changed request does not work in angular 6

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I have following function which calls the refresh service to get new token for authorization:

```ts
private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  if(!this.isRefreshingToken) {
    this.isRefreshingToken = true;
    return this.authService.refreshToken()
    .subscribe((response)=> {
      if(response) {
        const httpsReq = request.clone({
          url: request.url.replace(null, this.generalService.getUserId())
        });
        return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(httpsReq, response.accessToken));
      }
      return <any>this.authService.logout();
    }, err => {
      return <any>this.authService.logout();
    }, () => {
      this.isRefreshingToken = false;
    })
  } else {
    this.isRefreshingToken = false;
    return this.authService.currentRefreshToken
    .filter(token => token != null)
    .take(1)
    .map(token => {
      return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(request, token));
    })
  }
}
```

When the response is not undefined and request is returned back it does not call the new request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the thing was that the bearer was quoted like below:

[image]

But I have still one issue the request does not invoke the new request, when I refresh the page it gives data with new token, instead like I previously had unauthorized error.